# Hibernate Query Count

Tags: hibernate

Is there any way to count the number of queries done internally by Hibernate in a transaction or thread?  I looked into Hibernate interceptors, but it wasn't obvious which APIs I should override to increment counters.  My goal is to build an alarm to notify me when query count for a certain request exceeds some threshold, so I can optimize it as needed.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 4):

This question is old but I think it can help other people.

The library Spring Hibernate Query Utils (https://github.com/yannbriancon/spring-hibernate-query-utils) provides a query counter per thread that can be used in the integration tests to check the number of queries generated per request.

There is an example in the README:

```java
...
import com.yannbriancon.interceptor.HibernateQueryInterceptor;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class NotificationResourceIntTest {
    @Autowired
    private HibernateQueryInterceptor hibernateQueryInterceptor;

    @Test
    public void saveFile_isOk() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the query to 0 and allow the counting
        hibernateQueryInterceptor.startQueryCount();

        // Call the resource that we want to test
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(get("/rest/notifications"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        // Get the query count for this thread and check that it is equal to the number of query you expect, let's say 4.
        // The count is checked and we detect potential n+1 queries.
        Assertions.assertThat(hibernateQueryInterceptor.getQueryCount()).isEqualTo(4);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This article helps you?

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19807.html

You can do something like:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactoryForApplication();
Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
stats.setStatisticsEnabled(true);

// All of the queries that have executed.
String[] queries = stats.getQueries();
```

And so on...

Comment: Say 10 requests all come in together, each runs in its own transaction or thread.  Can I tell query count for each request?  Or are they all mixed together?

Comment: They are all mixed together for a single [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getStatistics()) (which normally you just have one per application). You should explore the Statistics API there is a method called getQueryStatistics(String queryString) probably is what you want.

Comment: The third line (setStatisticsEnabled) really helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little library (https://github.com/Lemick/hibernate-query-asserts) that can assert the count of SQL queries by type (SELECT, INSERT, ..) generated by Hibernate in your Spring tests, this way, you can be warned whenever the SQL statements change in your tests, and prevent N+1 selects. You can take a look here at the project if you want to know how this is implemented.

A test example that demonstrates the purpose:

```
@Test
@AssertHibernateSQLCount(inserts = 1)
void create_one_entity_from_endpoint() {
    BlogPost requestBody = new BlogPost("My new blog post");

    BlogPost responseBody = restTemplate.postForObject("/blogPosts", requestBody, BlogPost.class);

    assertEquals("My new blog post", responseBody.getTitle(), "The blog post created is returned");
}
```